# createElement function not working with MAC Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have below code to create Drop-down:

Below code for HTML to render Drop-down as:

```
<input class="form-control selectedTextBox mobile-space" list="rider" type="text" id="ridername" placeholder="FirstName LastName"
    data-bind="trimedValue: item().Name, datalist: {
        options: app.viewModel.riderProfiles(),
        optionsValue: 'Id',
        optionsText: 'Name',
        value: app.viewModel.selectedRiderId
    }" />
```

Below is Knockout.js handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datalist = (function () {
    function getVal(rawItem, prop) {
        var item = ko.unwrap(rawItem);
        return item && prop ? ko.unwrap(item[prop]) : item;
    }

    function findItem(options, prop, ref) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(options, function (item) {
            return ref === getVal(item, prop);
        });
    }
    return {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var setup = valueAccessor(),
                textProperty = ko.unwrap(setup.optionsText),
                valueProperty = ko.unwrap(setup.optionsValue),
                dataItems = ko.unwrap(setup.options),
                myValue = setup.value,
                koValue = allBindingsAccessor().value,
                datalist = document.createElement("DATALIST");

            // create an associated <datalist> element
            datalist.id = element.getAttribute("list");
            document.body.appendChild(datalist);

            // when the value is changed, write to the associated myValue observable
            function onNewValue(newVal) {
                var dataItems = ko.unwrap(setup.options),
                    selectedItem = findItem(dataItems, textProperty, newVal),
                    newValue = selectedItem ? getVal(selectedItem, valueProperty) : void 0;

                if (ko.isWriteableObservable(myValue)) {
                    myValue(newValue);
                }
            }

            // listen for value changes
            // - either via KO's value binding (preferred) or the change event
            if (ko.isSubscribable(koValue)) {
                koValue.subscribe(onNewValue);
            } else {
                ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
                    onNewValue(this.value);
                });
            }

            // init the element's value
            // - either via the myValue observable (preferred) or KO's value binding
            if (ko.isObservable(myValue) && myValue()) {
                element.value = getVal(findItem(dataItems, valueProperty, myValue()), textProperty);
            } else if (ko.isObservable(koValue) && koValue()) {
                onNewValue(koValue());
            }
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var setup = valueAccessor(),
                datalist = element.list,
                dataItems = ko.unwrap(setup.options),
                textProperty = ko.unwrap(setup.optionsText);

            // rebuild list of options when an underlying observable changes
            datalist.innerHTML = "";
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(dataItems, function (item) {
                var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
                option.value = getVal(item, textProperty);
                datalist.appendChild(option);
            });
            ko.utils.triggerEvent(element, "change");
        }
    };})();
```

And with only MAC(OS) & Safari (Web-Browser) below error message is shown as:

> Message: Unable to process binding "datalist: function () {return { options:app.viewModel.riderProfiles(),optionsValue:'Id',optionsText:'Name',value:app.viewModel.selectedRiderId} }"
>
> Message: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'u.innerHTML=""')

Comment: Could it be that Safari just doesn't support the `list` attribute as it's part of  the `<datalist>` spec? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Can you please share solution for editable drop-down with Safari browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML  element contains a set of  elements that represent the values available for other controls.

But "Safari" browser does not support it.